# Microsoft News API: What is the query the news which must contains those keywords

Tags: api, search, xamarin

Does Microsoft News Search API allow to have queries which query the news that contains all those specified keywords?

At the moment, I could query the news but those news matched were the match 1 or more of the keywords. I want to refine the search more. I want to have news which contains all those keywords.

e.g.

```
 queries: Cat in a bottle  
 Responsed News: e.g. Cat who drink in a bottle
```

Comment: have you tried using a boolean "cat & bottle" in your query?

Answer (score 0):

Provide a search string with all your keywords (but not categories):

i.e. `q=stackoverflow%20has%20never%20placed%20cat%20in%20bottle`

[News Search API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760793(v=bsynd.50).aspx):

> The user's search query string. If the query string is empty (for example, q=), the response will include the top news stories.
>   The query string may contain Bing Advanced Operators. For example, to limit news to a specific domain, use the site: operator.